# input type file для обычной кнопки

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

У меня есть кнопка, как сделать при нажатии на нее загрузку файла в форму?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<button><label for="file">Кнопка</label></button>
<input id="file" type="file" style="display: none;">
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
<button onclick="file.click()">Кнопка</button>
<input id="file" type="file" hidden />
```